# Problem with C# Return After Converting From List to Array

Tags: c#

I am attempting to solve a problem. There is a bunch of gibberish, but after every vowel is a letter that is used to piece together a legible word. My code always returns either

```
System.Char[]
System.Char[]
System.Char[]
```

or

```
System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.Char]
System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.Char]
System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.Char]
```

for some random reason. I know it's a simple problem but I'm having so much trouble with it.

Here is my code currently:

```
using System;
using System.Linq; 
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class Program
{
  public static string Decypher(string encryptedMessage)
  {
    List<char> letters = new List<char>();
    char[] vowels = {'a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u'};
    for (int i = 0; i <= encryptedMessage.Count() - 1; i++)
      {
        if (vowels.Contains(encryptedMessage[i]))
        {
          letters.Add(encryptedMessage[i + 1]);
          i++;
        }
      }

    return letters.ToString();
  }
  
  public static void Main(string[] args)
  {
    string testCase1 = "fksahnlgueyilfhnalfkjnhdssaokjfhndsfiwaourhnfdjgbalfkjshedfnsf";
    string testCase2 = "mkjmnacioudhrieeqwthyiugueresjfgwatfhwghfnhgnffn";
    string testCase3 = "elruoqywicwnjksakvfbsgyohuehnghiefhggadfgsfsfs";

    Console.WriteLine(Decypher(testCase1));
    Console.WriteLine(Decypher(testCase2));
    Console.WriteLine(Decypher(testCase3));
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some types have a custom `ToString` method but most just inherit the default implementation from the `Object` class, which is to return the name of the type. That's exactly what you're seeing from this:

```cs
return letters.ToString();
```

If what you actually want is a `string` containing the characters from `letters` then the most obvious option is to use the `string` constructor that takes a `char` array as an argument:

```cs
return new string(letters.ToArray());
```

Comment: @interblade, note that, at SO, it is preferred that you don't add comments just to say thank you. Upvotes and accepting answers is implied thanks enough. Comments should be reserved for getting or giving information relevant to a question or answer.

Answer (score 2):

`.ToString` doesn't turn your list of chars into a string, it just returns the string representation of the object, which is for `List<char>` is just `System.Collections.Generic.List1[System.Char]` as you're seeing.

Try using a `StringBuilder` instead of a `List<char>`:

```
StringBuilder letters = new StringBuilder();

letters.Append('a');
letters.Append('b');
letters.Append('c');

Console.WriteLine(letters.ToString());
>>> abc
```